# Where In query in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

I am trying to build this query which has a where In. But, I get the error when I run it.

```
$tickets =  DB::table('ticket_details')
                ->join('client_details', 'client_details.client_id', '=', 'ticket_details.client_id')
                ->select();

               if($archived){
                   $tickets->where('ticket_details.is_archived', '=', '1');
                } else {
                   $tickets->where('ticket_details.is_archived', '=', '0');
                }
                if($user->hasRole('ABM')) {
                    $tickets->whereIn('client_details.client_area', $regions);
                }
```

But this query gives me this error:

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, object given, called in 
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/levigo/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php on line 313 and defined
```

What is wrong with the whereIn method here?/

Comment: Where is `$regions` defined? If it is a laravel collection object (very likely), then try to use `$regions->toArray()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before executing this code you should check if $regions is an array. When trying to obtain an array from the database but no results are found, the object is not initialized as an array.

```
$tickets =  DB::table('ticket_details')
                  ->join('client_details', 'client_details.client_id', '=','ticket_details.client_id')
                  ->select();

$tickets->where('ticket_details.is_archived', '=', $archived ? '1' : '0');  

if($user->hasRole('ABM')) {
   if( count( $regions ) ) $tickets->whereIn('client_details.client_area', $regions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that $regions variable is not an array (can't guess from the code you pasted) maybe it is an Illuminate\Support\Collection or Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection

hope this helps